# Why Does My Step Function Parallel Branch Not Go To The Error Handling Task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

**Desired Result:** When any task within the parallel branch fails, I would like to report the error by `catch`ing it. It should go to the "Report Error" task.

**Actual Result:** It stops at a specific task in the branch, and does not report the error.

What do I need to do to have the failed branch's error go to the final task? I'm `catch`ing `STATES.ALL`.

[image: Step Function State Machine]

Comment: Please add a \*simplified\* version of your state machine definition code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Looking at the input of the "Report Error" Task, it required a lot of information from previous tasks e.g. "Get Secrets" that were not available to the task.

To manoeuvre this issue, new information had to be created after the catch and before the "Report Error" task for it to work.